# Query on a nested field using elastic4s on ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

I want to query a nested document that is indexed in ES.

For example, the nested field is `user` which contains two fields `id` and `name`. I want to query all documents where the name exactly matches the field `user.name`.

Cannot figure out how to use the elastic4s DSL for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you do nested queries in elastic4s:

First of all, setting up the index such that you have a nested type:

```
  client.execute {
    create index "nested" mappings {
      "show" as {
        "actor" typed NestedType
      }
    }
  }
```

Then with some sample data

```
  client.execute(
    index into "nested/show" fields(
      "name" -> "game of thrones",
      "actor" -> Seq(
        Map("name" -> "peter dinklage", "birthplace" -> "Morristown"),
        Map("name" -> "pedro pascal", "birthplace" -> "Santiago")
      )
    )
  )
```

Then the key part. To search, you used the `nested` (or in elastic4s 1.4 beta, `nestedQuery`) to "drop into" the nested scope, where you can search using any standard query type. Here I am just using a simple `termQuery` search.

```
client.execute {
  search in "nested/show" query nested("actor").query(termQuery("actor.name" -> "dinklage"))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
clientProvider.getClient.execute {
    (search in path)
      .query(
        nested("[something].user").query(
        bool(must(
          term("something.user.name" -> name)
        ))
        )
      )
    }
```

Since I'm not familiar with your structure i will provide my own example and maybe you could go from there:

- venueData consist of meta data about a venue and the venue itself.
- venue got a list of employees that is a NestedType nested()
- employee got an id that is of type Long

---

```
def venueByEmployeeId(employeeId: Long): Future[Option[VenueData]] = {
    clientProvider.getClient.execute {
    (search in path)
      .query(
        nested("venue.employees").query(
        bool(must(
          term("venue.employees.id" -> employeeId)
        ))
        )
      )
    }.map(_.getHits.jsonToList[VenueData].headOption)
}
```

The thing I did forget about the query is that you need to write the entire path **term("venue.employees.id" -> employeeId)**